# Using soundloud API to get all tracks from user feed

Tags: javascript, api, soundcloud

Currently, I'm attempting to use the javascript soundcloud API wrapper to get all of the sounds from a users feed like this:

```
$('head').append("<script src='https://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk/sdk-3.0.0.js'>");

SC.initialize({
    client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
    redirect_uri: '/callback.html'
});

// initiate auth popup
SC.connect(function() {
    SC.get('/me', function(me) {
        alert('Hello, ' + me.username);
    });
});

var dashTracks = SC.get('/me/activities/tracks/affiliated');
```

but when I view the console, there is the error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: SC is not defined
```

and I'm not quite sure how to get around it.

Answer (score 1):

Wait for the script to be loaded before executing your code.

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.type = 'text/javascript';
s.src = 'https://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk/sdk-3.0.0.js';
$('head').append(s);

s.onload = init;

function init() {
    SC.initialize({
        client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
        redirect_uri: '/callback.html'
    });

    SC.connect(function () {
        SC.get('/me', function (me) {
            alert('Hello, ' + me.username);
        });
    });

    var dashTracks = SC.get('/me/activities/tracks/affiliated');
}
```

Comment: Whoops, I do this already. Edited my OP to reflect how. I'm packaging this as a Chrome app that runs mostly in the background for soundcloud so I don't have any HTML that I edit beside the callback in the SC.initialize